# EF Core 2.1 Value Conversion Update Issue

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I ran into an issue using value conversion, which is new in EF Core 2.1, for List to string conversion.

Since I did not need to be able to filter the List of Enum values in the Database I decided to map my List of Enum Values to a comma delimited string with the int values.

The Conversion should look like this:

```
From: List<EnumType>{EnumType.Value1, EnumType.Value2}    
To: 1,2
```

Everything seemed to work fine but EF seems not to notice that the list of Enum values was changed and does not issue an update in the database. Is there a limitation that does not allow value conversion for lists?

The Value Conversion Code looks like this:

```
private const char ENUM_LIST_DELIMITER = ',';
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(x => x.Types)
    .HasConversion(x => ConvertToString(x), x => ConvertToEnumList<EnumType>(x));
}

private static List<TEnum> ConvertToEnumList<TEnum>(string value) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
  return value?.Split(ENUM_LIST_DELIMITER)
    .Select(Enum.Parse<TEnum>)
    .ToList();
}

private static string ConvertToString<TEnum>(IEnumerable<TEnum> value) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
  return string.Join(ENUM_LIST_DELIMITER, value.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)));
}
}
```

Comment: Value conversions work as expected. The problem is that (1) you are using mutable class `List<T>` (2) which also does not implement content equality, hence is compared by reference. Because of that, EF Core change tracker cannot detect changes. You should really consider replacing the list with some custom immutable class which implements equality (a.k.a. *value object").

Comment: Thank you very much - this helps me a lot to find out which solution to choose in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Value conversion on `List<T>` worked for me when using `DbContext.Set<T>.Update(entity)` instead of getting the entity from the context, changing some properties and then calling `.SaveChangesAsync()`. This is probably due to what @Ivan Stoev said regarding equality comparison. `Update()` marks all properties in an entity as changed. Perhaps not desired in all situations, but can be an quick fix.